# deserialize list of objects using json.net

Tags: .net, json, deserialization, json.net

i have this class

```
public class Image
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string url_40px { get; set; }
    public string url_50px { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public List<int> ancestor_ids { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public List<object> children_ids { get; set; }
    public string nodename { get; set; }
    public int num_parts { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public string __class__ { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

and i deserialize it like this

```
retObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Category)(jsonResp)
```

but for a list of category returned, how do i convert to `List<Category>`?
thanks

Comment: have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List<Category>)(jsonResp)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The type parameter for `DeserializeObject` has to be `List<Category>` instead of `Category`.

In C# it would be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(json)`

And In VB.Net it would be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Category))(json)`

Comment: hello, what is its an array off `category`?

Comment: You can use *any* type for the `DeserializeObject` method. Newtonsoft tries to deserialize the specified type and (in case of success) returns it. So you may also write `DeserializeObject(Of Category[])(json)`. (I don't know VB so maybe you have to write the array type different)

Comment: The VB for this would be JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Category))(json)