# NewtonSoft DeserializeObject<List<typename>> . What types server sends I donot know

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have similar question.

[deserialize list of objects using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220776/deserialize-list-of-objects-using-json-net)

Normally we do like below to deserialize a list of objects. But in my case I cannot hard code `List<Category>` since I do not know what will be the type.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(response.dtosString)
```

There will a property in json which will give me type name using that I can create a Type like below

```
string typename = string.Format("{0}, ABC.EDF", myresponse.dtoType);
Type resultType = Type.GetType(typename);
```

Now I want to use something like below

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<typename>>(myresponse.dtosString)
```

I tried below but not works since it says dynamic cannot be converted and need explicit conversion logic.

[Deserializing an unknown type in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246609/deserializing-an-unknown-type-in-json-net)

**SOLUTION:** Thanks to Chris for pointing me in right direction.

This is what I did

```
string typename = string.Format("{0}, ABC.EDF", myresponse.dtoType);
Type resultType = Type.GetType(typename);
var listType = typeof(List<>);
Type constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(resultType);
var myData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myresponse.dtosString, constructedListType);
```

After this I just provide myData to a read function which is in third party library which I donot have access to and that process the data.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you working with? Have you tried using `dynamic` [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) in C#?

Comment: If you look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm there are several overloads that take a Type object. Have you looked at these?

Comment: @adityap .. as I said in my question I tried dynamic..

Comment: @Chris.. I read it and normally use this DeserializeObject(String, Type).. here my problem is I cannot give List<Category> … service will give me what type of collection my result json has.. now I need to create Type which must List<xxx>

Comment: @Ziggler: Ah, of course. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661211/c-sharp-instantiate-generic-list-from-reflected-type looks like it should get you from your type to the appropriate `List<Type>`

Comment: @Chris.. I am looking at your suggestion...

Comment: @Chris... Thanks it works. Please post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Ziggler: Done! I think I've covered everything in there. If not though then feel free to comment and let me know what I missed that you think the answer needs or if its a lot you can always self-answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload that accepts a `Type` object. To construct a list of your type you'll need to do something like this:

```
var constructedListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(resultType);
var listType = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
```

Then you just need to use the appropriate deserialize overload:

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myresponse.dtosString, listType);
```

It is worth noting that myList will be of type Object and there is no easy way to strongly type it. Depending on what you need to do with it this may be ok or you may need to use `dynamic` to allow you to use it further down the line.

Comment: This is what I did...Thanks